# Upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 4 Causes Exception in EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just upgraded my site to ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta to make use of the awesome new Web API functionality, and my site is working great except for one page which uses a particular EditorTemplate, each line I comment out, it says there is an object ref. error on the line above it, I have commented everything else out of this file except for the variable declaration to truly illustrate the weirdness of this problem:

[image]

Could this be a bug in the new System.Web.Razor v2.0 .dll shipped with MVC 4? Running under MVC 3 unchanged works fine. Not sure how to get around this :S

**Update:**
Ok after further investigation, I had one other code piece I hadn't commented out which was:

```
<div class="opt"><button class="plus@(Html.Raw(ViewData["id"] != null ? " " + ViewData["id"] : null))">+</button>
<button class="minus@(Html.Raw(ViewData["id"] != null ? " " + ViewData["id"] : null))">-</button></div>
```

It's for creating a stylized spinner button and worked fine in MVC 3, as soon as I comment this out, my page loads fine and the phantom object reference error disappears. I will dissect this culprit html further and see what the new MVC 4 Razor parser could be dying on. Anyone have any initial thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that particular snippet of html/razor. It looks as if it's a cache issue with a generated page. (A page that is not being recompiled/updated) but without more info it will be hard to diagnose this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I worked out the issue by removing the Html.Raw() which caused it for some absurd reason. This is even after uninstalls of all other ASP.NET MVC versions and a fresh install of MVC 4. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

Ok it appeared that removing the `Html.Raw()` from the Razor snippet fixed this.

I think this is a new bug with ASP.NET MVC 4, or that Html.Raw() inside html tags are no longer valid. Hopefully an MVC 4 dev notices this post and might address it.

I have no idea why I used Html.Raw() in there so have taken it out and is all functioning fine now. :)

Comment: There is no such bug. I have used Html.Raw() inside HTML tags in Razor 2.0. Something else was happening. You should be using Html.AttributeEncode() though.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then, but I can tell you all I did was remove Html.Raw() from surrounding the variables. Unless it's a strange combination of ternary operators and encoding, which I doubt. Have you used Html.Raw() inside actual tag attributes though like above?

Comment: I used your exact code when I first commented yesterday and it works fine. I seriously doubt it's an issue with `Html.Raw()`. Would be a bit more helpful to see the surrounding html but you're definitely having strange issues :)

Comment: Note to self: If I get this again, I think it can also actually be caused by a problem with the direct line underneath it (an object in a dot notation which is failing)